# How can Enzyme check for component visibility?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I've attached a cut down version of an issue I am having. I have a simple `Checkbox` which I hide using `opacity : 0` depending on what is passed into the component containing the `Checkbox` (in this case `MyCheckbox`)

**MyCheckBox.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Checkbox, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  checkboxHiddenStyle: {
    opacity: 0
  }
});

export default function MyCheckbox(props) {
  const styles = useStyles(props);
  return (
    <div>
      <Checkbox
        {...props}
        className={props.data.length === 0 && styles.checkboxHiddenStyle}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have a component which uses `MyCheckbox` called `MyCheckboxesInUse` which results in one checkbox showing and the other being hidden.

How do I check the visibility of each of these in a Jest/Enzyme test ? I've looked at lots of posts but can't find something that works!

Code and test running here on CodeSandbox [image: Edit check-checkbox-hidden]

**MyCheckBoxesInUse.js**

```
import React from "react";
import MyCheckbox from "./MyCheckbox";
import "./styles.css";

export default function MyCheckboxesInUse() {
  const arrayWithNothing = [];
  const arrayWithSomething = [1];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hidden Checkbox</h1>
      <MyCheckbox data={arrayWithNothing} />
      <h1>Visible Checkbox</h1>
      <MyCheckbox data={arrayWithSomething} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**MyCheckbox.test.js**

```
import React from "react";

import Enzyme, { mount } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import MyCheckboxesInUse from "./MyCheckboxesInUse";
import MyCheckbox from "./MyCheckbox";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

test("Check that one checkbox is hidden and the other is visible", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<MyCheckboxesInUse />);

  const checkboxes = wrapper.find(MyCheckbox);
  expect(checkboxes).toHaveLength(2);

  //HOW DO I CHECK THAT ONE IS VISIBLE AND THE OTHER IS NOT ?
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tryout `jest-dom` from `testing-library`, but if you want to see how they implement what you want, check out their code: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/blob/master/src/to-be-visible.js

Comment: Thanks. Looks like what I need. When I tried it I get expect(...).not.toBeVisible is not a function. See updated CodeSandbox here ---> https://codesandbox.io/s/check-checkbox-hidden-with-jsdom-xgijx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark