# Why does jest-dom give the error "TypeError: expect(...).not.toBeVisible is not a function" when I use it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, automated-tests, enzyme

In relation to a previous question - [How can Enzyme check for component visibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406862/how-can-enzyme-check-for-component-visibility) I tried using `jest-dom` to specifically use their `toBeVisible` function.

Despite following the documentation I cannot get it to work in my test and get the error

`"TypeError: expect(...).not.toBeVisible is not a function"`

Fully reproduced in CodeSandbox here [image: Edit check-checkbox-hidden-with-jsdom]

```
import Enzyme, { mount } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import React from "react";
import MyCheckbox from "./MyCheckbox";
import MyCheckboxesInUse from "./MyCheckboxesInUse";


Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

test("Check that one checkbox is hidden and the other is visible", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<MyCheckboxesInUse />);

  const checkboxes = wrapper.find(MyCheckbox);
  expect(checkboxes).toHaveLength(2);

  //HOW DO I CHECK THAT ONE IS VISIBLE AND THE OTHER IS NOT ?
  expect(checkboxes.get(0)).not.toBeVisible();
  expect(checkboxes.get(1)).toBeVisible();
});
```

Comment: You'd need to follow the instructions and either extend `expect` implicitly or explicitly. But I also think it expects an HTML or SVG element, not a component.

Answer (score 26):

I was facing a similar issue. In my case, it was resolved by the following steps:-

- Adding the `@testing-library/jest-dom` package to the `devDependencies` instead of `dependencies` in the package.json file.

Next add one of the following:

1. Adding `import '@testing-library/jest-dom';` to the setupTests.js
2. Or adding in jest configuration (package.json): `"setupFilesAfterEnv": [ "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect" ]`

Comment: This solved my issue from using `react-script-tests` to using jest for generating test reports on the CI environment. Important part for me was adding the `setupFilesAfterEnv` to the jest config.

Answer (score 13):

The `expect().not.toBeVisible` method comes from the `@testing-library/jest-dom` library, since there is no setup or reference to that library the default `jest` expect is used (thus the function is not found). A quick fix would be to add this import to the top of your test file (assuming you have already imported the library into your project via npm or yarn):

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

For scalability you may want to add a `setupTest.js` file (reference here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/)

Answer (score 6):

importing `'@testing-library/jest-dom'` doesn't help me  but
importing `@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'` help me resolve the error.

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
```